# Output parameter of stored procedure not showing

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I can't seem to get my stored procedure to show the OUT Parameter when it is called. It just shows '0 row affected' with no display of the OUTPUT Variable. The OUTPUT is the value of a variable that was declared. This is my procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(IN `masterId` INT, IN `subId` INT,  OUT current_balance INT)
BEGIN
    declare current_balance INT;
    set current_balance = 2;   
END
```

This is how I am calling it:
call test('274', '399', @res)

Comment: Could it be because you are declaring the current_balance again inside the code block? That could make it a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have overridden the parameter with a local variable.

I prefer to give names to parameters to avoid conflicts:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(
    IN in_masterId INT,
    IN in_subId INT, 
    OUT out_current_balance INT
)
BEGIN
    set out_current_balance = 2;   
END;
```